# web api integration testing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, web-api-testing

I have an integrationtest project and a web api project in the same solution.
The integration tests use RestSharp to call the web api.
When running the integration tests I want the web api project to launch first.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is to Self Host the target WebApi project.  Then, if you want to run these tests on a build server etc, you don't need a web server installed.

[This is a pretty good walk-through](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api) on setting up a Self Host.

Essentially, you use the `HttpSelfHostServer` class with `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` to host the target project.

Comment: Is it possible to use RestSharp client with HttpSelfhostServer?

Comment: Yeah, you will be speaking HTTP so any HTTP client will do.  Self Hosting is like creating an in memory web server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698130/unit-testing-web-api-using-httpserver-or-httpselfhostserver#14698335 suggests to use HttpServer over HttpSelfHostServer